# Proving that the length-preserving OWF does not have polynomially bounded cycle

Tags: one-way-function

Here a cycle is the smallest positive integer such that $f^i(x) = x$.
Formally we want to prove that if $f$ is OWF then $\forall p(.)$ and sufficiently large $n$, $Exp(cyc_f(U_n))>p(n)$ where $n$ is length of input.

I understand that by applying Markov's inequality we get that,
if $Exp(cyc_f(U_n))>p(n)$ then for every polynomial $q(.)$, we have $Pr(cyc_f(U_n)) > q(n).p(n)] < 1/q(n)$.

If I try a proof by contradiction, it means that if $f$ is OWF then there exists polynomial $q(.)$, and we have $Pr(cyc_f(U_n)) > q(n).p(n)] \geq 1/q(n)$.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you generally want a proof by *contrapositive*, not *contradiction*.
To prove $A\implies B$ by contrapositive, we prove $\lnot B\implies \lnot A$.
Here, $A$ is "$f$ is an OWF", and $B$ is "$f$'s expected cycle length is super-polynomial".
Therefore, we want to prove that if $f$'s expected cycle length is bounded by some polynomial, then $f$ is not an OWF.
You can prove something is not an OWF by constructing an inverter that works with non-negligible probability.

With those clarifications, I'll give you the following hint

> If you **know** that an element $x$ has a cycle of length at most $p(x)$, i.e. $f^{i}(x) = x$ for some $i \leq p(n)$, how can you efficiently map from $f(x)\mapsto x$?

After answering this, you will need to argue that even knowing that *on average* (over $x$) the above holds suffices to build a good enough (to violate $f$ being a OWF) inverter.

Comment: Thank you very much